# OCaml : How to create a list of n 1's in

Tags: ocaml

What is the equivalent of the following Python code in OCaml?

`lst = [0] * N`

It seems to me that OCaml has not overloaded the `*` for Lists.

I have written the following function

```
let makeList i = if i = 0 then [] else 0 :: makeList (i-1)
```

Can I do something using a `for` loop or make the code shorter?

Comment: ``fun n -> Array.make n 0 |> Array.to_list``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [ocaml batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/List.html) :

```
List.make n 0
```

should make it (I have not tried it)

Comment: I get an error saying `Error: Unbound value List.make`

Comment: I guess this is because you did not install batteries : opam install batteries.

Comment: it works with batteries in toplevel environment : #requires "batteries";; open Batteries;; List.make 5 0;; will yield a list of 5 elements equal to 0.

Answer (score 6):

OCaml Standard library forms a minimal algebra, suitable for building user libraries on top of it. You should consider to use some of the available community libraries. There're many of them, Batteries, Core, Extlib, Containers, to name a few. If in doubt I would suggest to use `Core` library, at least because current state of the art [OCaml Book](https://realworldocaml.org/) is written with this library in mind. In `Core` there is a `List.init` function, that suits your needs:

```
open Core.Std
List.init 10 ~f:(const 0);;
- : int list = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
```

There is also a range list, that can make iota lists:

```
List.range 0 10;;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
```

Install core with

```
opam install core
```

To play with it in the toplevel, use `coretop` program (installed with core).
To compile the program, use corebuild, e.g., assuming that your code is in `example.ml`:

```
corebuild example.native
```

Comment: I don't know OCaml well, so I don't understand `~f:(const 0)`. However, this works fine, e.g. an array of ten floats: `List.init 10 (fun _ -> 0.0)`.

Comment: Or: `List.init 10 @@ Fun.const 0.`

Answer (score 3):

OCaml doesn't overload operators.

There is nothing in the standard library to create such lists, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Since ocaml 4.06 you can use:

```
List.init N (fun x->0)
```

Comment: The `x` name doesn't need to be bound. You might: `List.init n (fun _ -> 0)` or even just `List.init n (Fun.const 0)`